# Proof involving Hilbert Cube

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathbf 0$ be the sequence of real numbers with all the components equal to $0$ and, for each $n \in \Bbb N$, let $δ_n$ be the sequence of real numbers whose n-th component equals $1$ and all other components are $0$.

Let $I^\infty$ be the Hilbert Cube in $l^2$, that is $I^\infty$ = { $(x_n)_n \in l^2: |x_n| < \frac1n$ }

Show that $I^\infty$ is not open in $l^2$

My attempt at the proof was to assume $I^\infty$ is open and look for a contradiction but I must have done something incorrectly or this is not the best approach. Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that a set is not open, it suffices to show that its complement is not closed.

To do so, it suffices to find a sequence in the complement of $I^\infty$ whose limit lies in $I^\infty$.

To that end, consider the sequence $[(x_k^{(n)})]_{n=1}^\infty \subset \ell^2$ defined by
$$
x^{(n)}_k = 
\begin{cases}
0 & k \leq n\\
2/n & k > n
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_k^{(n)}) = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!